# Почему вместо заголовков окон выводятся числа (GetWindowText)?

Tags: winapi, c++

Выводятся не заголовки (caption) окон, а числа в 16-ричной системе счисления. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Вот есть код:

```
BOOL CALLBACK ew(HWND h, LPARAM lp)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    LPTSTR wtch = L"";
    if (IsWindowVisible(h)) {
        GetWindowText(h, wtch, 20);
        cout << wtch << endl;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    EnumWindows(ew, 0);
    system("Pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

А разве не нужно выделить буффер под возвращаемый текст?
Используй GetWindowTextLength, чтобы узнать длину заголовка.

```
    const int TWENTY = 20;
    const HWND thisHWnd = (HWND)0x0002041C;

    int length = GetWindowTextLength(thisHWnd) + 1; // +1 for '\0' symbol

    WCHAR buffer20[TWENTY];
    LPWSTR bufferFull = new WCHAR[length];

    GetWindowText(thisHWnd, bufferFull, length);
    GetWindowText(thisHWnd, buffer20, sizeof(buffer20));

    std::wcout << buffer20 << std::endl << bufferFull;

    delete bufferFull;
```

Comment: Нет. Ваш ответ не к месту. Если я выделю буфер размером меньшим, чем буфер строки кэпшна, то в выделенный буфер просто запишется часть строки кэпшна окна, а не вся строка!

Comment: Буфер действительно необходимо выделять, т.к. wtch указывает на область памяти, недоступную для записи.

Comment: @AlexeyM, Если бы я не выделял буфер, то сборка просто бы не скомпилировалась, вылетел бы мэсэдж Access Violation !

Comment: @LOLPADT, где именно в коде, по вашему мнению, выделяется буфер?

Comment: Нет. В данном случае пустая строка (т.е. фактически нулевой байт) окажется после загрузки PE-файла в недоступном для записи месте. И даже так, он всё равно имеет длину всего в 2 символа WCHAR.

Comment: Выделение. Только буфер маленький и вероятно, как указал @AlexeyM, read-only.

Comment: Хорошо. А какую рабочую альтернативу вы бы предложили, товарищи?

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: @Yak SD, ошибка...RunTime Error =)

Comment: @LOLPADT, интересно, а ты hWnd окна тот же оставил? Нужно свой брать :)
И ошибка где? У меня всё компилится и запускается.